# Implicit declaraction of function strnstr

Tags: c

I have a problem, I am trying to do my own function strnstr, my function works but when I tried to compare my function with the one in the library, it's said: implicit declaraction of function strnstr whereas I have the header <string.h> in my code I don't understand where is my error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        i++;
        str++;
    }
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_strnstr(const char *str, const char *to_find, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    if (ft_strlen(to_find) == 0)
        return ((char *)str);
    while (str[i] != '\0' && i < len)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (str[i + j] == to_find[j])
        {
            j++;
            if (to_find[j] == '\0')
                return ((char *)str + i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}


int main()
{
    char test[50];

    strcpy(test, "Hey guys, you you");

    printf("%p\n", ft_strnstr(test, "you", 15));
    printf("%p\n", strnstr(test, "you", 10));
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's no `strnstr()` defined by the [C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html), or by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: This non-standard function comes from BSD and if your system provides it, you'll have to check its documentation for the proper include files.  On Linux, for instance, you must `#include <bsd/string.h>` instead, and link with `-lbsd`.

Comment: `strnstr()` is, apparently, a [FreeBSD extra](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strnstr&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-current&arch=default&format=html): "[...] Since the strnstr() function is a FreeBSD specific API, it should only be used when portability is not a concern."

Comment: thanks guys I understand now I didn't see that it was from anoher library